# Xamarin:Different between ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction and BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth, connectivity

I wanted to know what is the different between ConnectivityAction and Action_State_Change.

At the moment, I am having a broadcastReceiver which listen to ConnectivityAction to check the wifi enable/disable state. In addition, I used ConnectivityAction to listen Bluetooth enable/disable state.

In Action_State_Change, I can do the same to detect enable/disable the Bluetooth by checking the intent State_On.

The difference I have between ConnectivityAction and Action_State_Change is: When I register ConnectivityAction in onStart and unregister it in onStop in my Activity, then when user select the enable/disable in setting screen, the receiver still receive the message. On the other hand, if I used Action_State_Change, if the user select the enable/disable in setting screen, my broadcast receiver with Action_State_Change won't receive the message.

What is the different between the two Action Filter.

Answer (score 0):

[CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) - A change in **network** connectivity has occurred.

[ACTION_STATE_CHANGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_STATE_CHANGED) - Broadcast Action: The state of the local **Bluetooth** adapter has been changed.

The first applies to any network change, the second specifically to the Bluetooth adapter

Comment: If I use the first one to check the Bluetooth wouldn't have any concern right. Coz at the moment, everything seems to be fine when using the first option.